# Cassandra integration in play framework 2.6 with java

Tags: java, playframework, cassandra

What is the best way to integrate cassandra cluster with playframework 2.6 and I am using Java as the main language .

1. I need to add the cassandra cluster details in the configuration file, I cant able to find any samples for this ?
2. How to handle cassandra session in reactive way ?

Comment: Hi playframework team , Any  suggession .